# Dataframe does not return desired result

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {
   'A':  ['d','d','d','d','d','d','g','g','g','g','g','g','k'
    ,'k','k','k','k','k'],
   'B': [5,5,6,7,5,6,-6,7,7,6,-7,7,-8,7,-6,6,-7,50],
   'C': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
   'S': [2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2012,2012,2014,2015,2016
    ,2012,2013,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2014]     
    } );

 df = (df.B + df.C).groupby([df.A,df.S]).agg(['sum','size'])
.unstack(fill_value=0)

df1 = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()

new_cols= list(zip(df1.columns.get_level_values(0),
['total'] * len(df.columns)))
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_cols)
df2 = pd.concat([df1,df], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

df2.columns = ['_'.join((col[0], str(col[1]))) for col in df2.columns]
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace('sum_','')
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace('size_','#')

df_without_2012 = df2.sort_index(axis=1).loc[:, '2013':'2016']
df2[((df2['2012'] < 0) | (df_without_2012.sum(axis=1) > 21)) 
& (df_without_2012 > 0).all(axis=1)]

    #2012#2013#2014#2015#2016#total 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 total
A                                               
d      2    1    1   1    1    6     13   6    7    8    6    40
g      2    1    1   1    1    6    -11   8    8    8    7    20
```

2 questions;

- `df2` needs to **not** return 'g', as in the last line the sum should be
  over 21 and it is not. what is incorrect?
- secondly, I'd like to have
  the years next to the #years.

EDIT;

```
-11 8 8 8 7   20   FALSE
 -9 8 8 8 7   22   TRUE
  8 8 8 8 7   39   TRUE
  4 4 4 4 4   20   FALSE
```

> 21   &    ALL COLUMNS +    or   2013:2016 +, 2012 -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explanation is easy - `total` column is sum columns from `2012` to `2016`.

```
print (-11 +  8  +  8  +  8  +  7)
20
```

And `df_without_2012` are summed only columns from `2013` to `2016`, so sum is `31`:

```
print (8  +  8  +  8  +  7)
31
```

and

```
31 > 21
True
```

answer for second question is add `.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)`:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df1,df], axis=1)
        .sort_index(axis=1)
        .sort_index(axis=1, level=1) 

print (df2)
   #2012  2012  #2013  2013  #2014  2014  #2015  2015  #2016  2016  #total  \
A                                                                            
d      2    13      1     6      1     7      1     8      1     6       6   
g      2   -11      1     8      1     8      1     8      1     7       6   

   total  
A         
d     40  
g     20
```

EDIT:

If there is more masks, I think the best for testing is use:

```
df_without_2012 = df2.sort_index(axis=1).loc[:, '2013':'2016']
m1 = df2['2012'] < 0
m2 = df_without_2012.sum(axis=1) > **0**
m3 = (df_without_2012 > 0).all(axis=1)
m4 = df2.total > 21
print (m1)
print (m2)
print (m3)
print (m4)

mask = m1 & m2 **& m4** | m3 & m4
print (mask)

print (df2[mask])
```

Comment: I know, but not the result I need. What I need is any row where all columns are positive and any row where 2013:2016 are positive and 2012 is negative. For ALL these rows I need them to be > a certain value.

Comment: hmm, but condition is (column 2012 < 0 OR all columns without 2012 > 21) AND all columns without 2012 positive. So output is correct - in `g` (True OR True) AND True

Comment: `g` -11  `True`, 31 `True`, 8    8    8    7 `True`

Comment: so the code isn't right, I know. what do I need to change? total > 21 & either all columns positive | 2013:2016 positive and 2012 negative.

Comment: need fourth condition? for `g` (20 > 21 False & -11   8    8    8    7 False OR   8    8    8    7 True AND -11 True) ?

Comment: Ok, it seems more complicated. I think the best approach is create masks `m1`, `m2`.. `mn`, test them and then combine them with `AND (&)` and `OR (|)`, maybe `XOR(^)` or `NOT(~)`. If use brackets, you get more combinations like  `mask = (m1 & m2 | m3) & m4` or `mask = (m1 & m2) | (m3 & m4)`, so deeping testing is necessary I think.

Comment: I gave an example in the question

Comment: Thank you. ;) I hope it works now perfect, because if use more conditions it is no easy

Comment: Is posssible go to chat?

Comment: sure, where and how?

Comment: I dont know, now I have no option for move conversation to chat.

Comment: cause I'm not over 100?

Comment: I try check it, but i answered the most of your question and I alreade upvote it. So I cant do more, sorry.